# Duplicating a record in Rails except for one attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I am getting the duplication of last Expense record after the creation of new record but I want to exclude one attribute while duplication that is **:description_other, " "**.

expenses_controller.rb

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController

 # GET /expenses/new
  def new
    if Expense.last.present?
      @expense = Expense.last.dup
    else
      @expense = Expense.new
    end
   end

def expense_params
      params.require(:expense).permit(:date, :description, :description_other, :trips, :fare, :credit)
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">

    <%= form_for(@expense) do |f| %>

   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <span class="datetime"><%= f.date_select :date %></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :credit %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :credit, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.select(:description, options_for_select([['PLEASE SELECT...', ''],['METRO', 'METRO'], ['BUS', 'BUS'], ['TAXI', 'TAXI'], ['OTHERS', 'OTHERS'], ['FOOTLOOSE', 'FOOTLOOSE']]), {}, {class: "form-control", id: "expense_description"}) %>
  <br>
  <div id="otherDesc">
    <%= f.text_field :description_other, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :trips %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :trips, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :fare %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :fare, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div style="margin-left: 70px;" class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit @expense.new_record? ? "Create Expense" : "Update Expense", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
  </div>

  <% end %>

</div>
</div>
```

I have tried but unable to get the desired result.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
<div id="otherDesc">
<%= f.text_field :description_other, class: "form-control", value: " "%>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent ! It is working as expected with less modification.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen  It wont work bro. What about first time expense creation.I will fill otherDesc field with nil

Answer (score 1):

**use tap and then exclude property by setting to nil**

```
def new
  if Expense.last.present?
    # exclude here
    @expense  = Expense.last.dup.tap do | exp |
                  exp.description_other = nil  
                end
  else
    @expense = Expense.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I got the functionality working but when I create a new expense it directs towards the update action.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen what you are expecting ? To hit create action only ?

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen If you want that to hit create.Check I updated code.

Comment: I tried for both answers and his answer did it but still I was thinking to whom should I accept and finally he answered correctly at the first position so I accept him.Anyways, keep it up!

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen simple question bro. If you r sending otherDesc field as nothing, everytime it will store nil. If that's case why you created that field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156272/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-krishnar).